# Casting double to DateTime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datetime

I have converted my Datetime object from VB.Net to double using the following code:

```
Dim currentDate as DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim newdo as Double = currentDate.ToOADate()
Console.WriteLine(newdo) // output: 43742.1551505093
```

Then if I convert following double value to DateTime in SQL Server it shows me date which is two days in advance:

```
select cast(43742.1551505093 as datetime)
```

Output for the query is **2019-10-06 03:43:25.003**

Expected Value is **2019-10-04 03:43:25.003**

Comment: refer to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=netframework-4.8 `An OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose integral component is the number of days before or after midnight, 30 December 1899` But in SQL Server, 0 is `1900-01-01` . That is a 2 days diff. Subtract `2` from that value before `cast()` to `datetime`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an Excel format.  You can convert using:

```
select dateadd(second, (43742.1551505093 % 1) * 24*60*60, dateadd(day, 43742.1551505093, '1899-12-30'))
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support `dateadd_big()`, so it is simplest to add the days and seconds separately.